# How to interpolate multiple strings in a list structure with stringr package

Tags: r, string, data-structures, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with two variables: one with long names and one with short names of football clubs.

```
df <- structure(list(teams_names_long = c("Bayer Leverkusen", "Brighton & Hove Albion", 
"Deportivo La Coruña", "Eintracht Frankfurt", "Huddersfield Town"
), teams_names_short = c("Leverkusen", "Brighton", "La Coruña", 
"Eint Frankfurt", "Huddersfield")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I need to obtain an list with the same structure as the one resulting from the routine below:

```
desired_structure <- c(
      "Bayer Leverkusen" = "Leverkusen",
      "Brighton & Hove Albion" = "Brighton",
      "Deportivo La Coruña" = "La Coruña",
      "Eintracht Frankfurt" = "Eint Frankfurt",
      "Huddersfield Town" = "Huddersfield")
```

I attempted to do this with the following routine:

```
best_attempt <- str_flatten(
    str_glue(
      '"{teams_names_long_short$teams_names_long}"',
      " = ",
      '"{teams_names_long_short$teams_names_short}"'
    ),
    ", ")
```

Comment: `desired_dtructure <- tibble::deframe(df)`

Comment: That desired vector is a named vector: `desired_structure <- setNames(df$teams_names_short, df$teams_names_long)`.

Comment: `desired_dtructure <-with(df, setNames(team_names_short, team_names_long))`

Comment: @Onyambu Your `with/setNames` is 2 characters longer than my `setNames` :).

Comment: `with(` only really helps win code-golf if the object name (`df`) is more than 6 characters, until then `with` does not win ;-)

Comment: tibble::deframe(df) delivers the desired structure but does not have the = designation between vectors